# Guardar fichero por cada ejecución del notebook

Tags: python, jupyter, pyspark

Necesito guardar cada ejecución de un notebook de PySpark en un path que tengo.
Solo necesito que se guarde el nombre del fichero con el tiempo que ha tardado cada ejecución del notebook. No necesito que se guarde el fichero, solo como un registro histórico, ya que cada vez que quiero consultar el del día anterior desaparece. Si alguien sabe si esto es posible, agradeceria que me lo comentara o me dijese alguna librería. Gracias

He puesto esto, a ver si me podéis ayudar.

```
def move_added(geo, path_macro_out): #Poner el archivo que se desee registrar y donde se va a registrar)
    if not files:
        return

    new_dir = os.path.join(dest, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")) #Tendrá un output de la última modificación
    if not os.path.exists(new_dir):
        os.makedirs(new_dir)

    for file in files:
        path = os.path.join(dest, file)
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            shutil.move(path, new_dir)

move_added(geo, path_to_watch) #Se transfiere el fichero con la última modificación.
```

Lo que necesito es que en cada ejecución del notebook se quede registrado cada fichero en hdfs, lo que viene a ser el tiempo que tarda cada fichero en ejecutarse. Por que cada vez que lanzo una prueba se borra todo el histórico y tengo que hacer un pantallazo para saber que hizo en la ejecución anterior.
Gracias

Comment: Por favor agrega lo que has intentado / investigado. Un saludo :)

Comment: Hola, no me queda del todo claro que es lo que agregasste y donde está fallando. Podrás agregar en el codigo la linea en cuestion y que esperas que haga esa linea?